# What is the Rails 4 way to deal with filters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, filter

**Background:** I have a few filters which have to be available through every CRUD page on the system: search, livesearch, column sorting and pagination;

This is what I currently have:

```
.lib/record_filters.rb 
 module RecordFilters

 @@valid_directions = %w[asc desc]

 def search_for(record)
   record.present? ? where('name LIKE ?', record+"%") : all
 end

 def records_matching(search_term)
   where('name LIKE ?', search_term+"%").map(&:name)
 end

 def order_records_by(attribute, direction)
   order(sort_table_by(attribute) +" "+ sort_records_order_by(direction))
 end

 private

 def sort_table_by(attribute)
   column_names.include?(attribute) ? attribute : "name"
 end

 def sort_records_order_by(direction)
   @@valid_directions.include?(direction) ? direction : "asc"
 end

end

./app/models/ticket_type.rb
class TicketType < ActiveRecord::Base
  include RecordFilters 

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name  

end

./app/controllers/ticket_types_controller.rb
class TicketTypesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_ticket_type, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @ticket_types = TicketType.search_for(params[:search]).order_records_by(params[:sort], params[:direction]).paginate(per_page: 12, page: params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
      format.json { render json: TicketType.records_matching(params[:term]) }
     end
   end
   ...
end

./config/application.rb
...
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

**The problem:** Upon accessing the index on the browser, Rails returns NoMethodError for search_for

**Question:** What is the Rails Way to implement such filters? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because Ruby's `include` will add the module's methods **as instance methods**:

```
module A
  def value
    5
  end
end
class B
  include A
end
puts B.new.a # prints 5
puts B.a # fails
```

If you want them as **class methods**, like the class object itself was extended, use `extend`:

```
method A
  def value
    5
  end
end
class C
  extend A
end
puts C.a # prints 5
puts C.new.a # fails
```

You can also, if you really want `include`, define some new methods in the module's `included` callback:

```
module A
  def self.included(mod)
    # mod is whatever (module or class) included A.
    # in this case, it's B.
    mod.class_eval do
      def self.value
        "class"
      end
      # there's no reason to do this here, instead of
      # in the module itself, but just for demonstration purposes:
      def inst
        "inst"
      end
    end
  end
end

class B
  include A
end

puts B.value # prints "class"
puts B.new.inst # prints "inst"
```

Comment: Feeling so stupid for not thinking about that, thanks @Ven !

Comment: @FilipeGorgesReuwsaat added something about `included` :)

Answer (score 2):

Your methods are getting added as instance methods, but you're calling them like class methods, I'd recommend you look into http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html to implement the concern pattern for your models.

Comment: I thought about doing that at first, but there were many complaints around about using concerns so I ended up making a module on the lib. What is your opinion on that?

Comment: Subjective, like everyone else's :P. Concerns add a lot for some specific use cases, like running some stuff in the constructor, etc. It's usually not really needed, but I'll make a note about included...

Comment: personally, the ActiveSupport concern library is very handy for making shared model logic, that is what's for after all! It's also not just a syntactic nicety, it solves very real problems with module dependencies. What were people complaining about?

Comment: @maniacalrobot That's exactly what I thought about, but here, this is one of them: http://blog.coreyhaines.com/2012/12/why-i-dont-use-activesupportconcern.html